# unit test a method that has dependency on StreamReader for reading file

Tags: c#, unit-testing

how can i test a methods that reads file using StreamReader , 
i Dont want to create file on hard drive every time i run test ,
i just need sr.ReadToEnd(); to be my expected string

```
public class ConfigStore : IConfigStore
{
    public string ReadFile(string FileName)
    {
        string result;
        using(StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(FileName) )
        {
            result= sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //logic to be tested
        return result+1;
    }
}
```

and my test class

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Shoud_Add_1_To_File_Content()
    {
        //arrange
        ConfigStore configStore = new ConfigStore();


        //act
        var returntype=configStore.ReadFile("config.json");

        //assert
        Assert.AreEqual ("test1",returntype);

    }
}
```

note:code is just for testing purpose not real business case .

thanks.

Comment: As a unit test, is it worth to test how you read a file ? Shouldn't it be an integration test ?

Comment: @Zysce the intention is not to test reading  file i just want to test ReadFile Method.because there might be some other logic there in method

Comment: I suggest using [System.IO.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Abstractions/)

Comment: By testing the ReadFile method, you test the StreamReader as well, is it worth it ?

Comment: Put the logic being tested in its own method, one which accepts a stream or string.  Mock the stream or string that you send it.  There's no need to unit test whether or not the framework can read a file.

Comment: You can add a file with content into your test project instead of creating a new file every time. Send the path of that file while invoking the test method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [System.IO.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Abstractions/) library to make your method unit testable.

You need to add a property `FileSystem` to your `ConfigStore` class.

```
// Default file system uses .NET Framework's File class
public IFileSystem FileSystem { get; set; } = new FileSystem();
```

Secondly, you need to use this file system instead of `StreamReader` or using `System.IO.File` directly:

```
public string ReadFile(string FileName)
{
    return FileSystem.File.ReadAllText();
}
```

Then, you need to implement a fake `IFileSystem` and override the necessary methods, for example in `File.Create` method you can instead add passed file name to a collection or do nothing.

Then the last step is to create an instance of this fake file system and assign it to `ConfigStore.FileSystem` so file system you provided will be used.

Comment: This answer really pointed me into the right direction! More information here: 

- https://dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-file-io
- http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Unit-Testing-C-File-Access-Code-with-SystemIOAbstractions